# storage allocation in c++

Tags: c++, initialization, switch-statement

I'm reading thinking in c++ chapter 6 initialization & cleanup.
The author said that:

> It's actually more likely that the compiler will follow the practice
>   in C of allocating all the storage for a scope at the opening brace of
>   that scope. It doesn't matter because, as a programmer, you can't
>   access the storage until it has been defined. Although the storage is
>   allocated at the beginning of the block, the constructor call doesn't
>   happen until the sequence point where the object is defined because
>   the identifier isn't available until then. The compiler even checks to
>   make sure that you don't put the object definition where the sequence
>   point only conditionally passes through it, such as in a switch
>   statement or somewhere a goto can jump past it.

And then the author gives an example as following:

```
class X {
public:
  X();
};

X::X() {}

void f(int i) {
  if(i < 10) {
   //! goto jump1; // Error: goto bypasses init
  }
  X x1;  // Constructor called here
 jump1:
  switch(i) {
    case 1 :
      X x2;  // Constructor called here
      break;
  // case 2 : // Error: case bypasses init
      X x3;  // Constructor called here
      break;
  }
} 

int main() {
  f(9);
  f(11);
}///:~
```

I don't understand why the above code is OK? According to my understanding, `x2` can be bypassed initialization if `i` is not `1`.

***Supplement:***

This sentence "It'a actually more likely that the compiler will follow the practice in C of allocating all the storage for a scope at the opening brace of that scope." also confused me.

According to the author's description, at the opening brace of the `switch`, the compiler has already allocated space for `x2` and `x3`. If this is the case, there is an opportunity for `x2` to be uninitialized(case 1 is not satisfied).

Answer (score 5):

> According to my understanding, x2 can be bypassed initialization if i is not 1.

No, either the `case 1` is executed, and `x2` is defined and then destroyed at the end of the `switch` block, or no case is executed and the entire `switch` block does nothing, so `x2` is not in scope, so it isn't initialized but it can't be referred to either. So either it exists and is safe to use, or it doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks Wakely. One more question, If I uncomment case 2:, there will be an error. Why?

Comment: Because then the program's control flow could jump to `case 2` and bypass the initialization of `x2`, which isn't allowed in C++, as the book says _"The compiler even checks to make sure that you don't put the object definition where the sequence point only conditionally passes through it, such as in a switch statement or somewhere a goto can jump past it."_

Comment: Hi Janathan, I've edited the question and asked one more question. Can you do me a favor once again.

Comment: "_there is an opportunity for `x2` to be uninitialized_" - No, because you can't refer to the object or use it. It doesn't matter if some (uninitialized) memory has been reserved for it - you cannot access that memory when `x2` is not in scope. That's the point that Eckel is making: although the compiler know in advance where the object will live in memory, the programmer cannot use the object until the reserved memory has been safely initialized

Answer (score 2):

C++ object initialization and destruction semantics are completely jump-safe (exception, goto , switch and loop constructs included).

(The only notable exception is inherited from the C standard library (setjmp/longjmp))

> 6.6 Jump statements
>
> <sup>2</sup> On exit from a scope (however accomplished), objects with automatic storage duration (3.7.3) that have been constructed in that scope are destroyed in the reverse order of their construction. [ Note: For temporaries, see 12.2. —end note ] ***Transfer out of a loop, out of a block, or back past an initialized variable with automatic storage duration involves the destruction of objects with automatic storage duration that are in scope at the point transferred from but not at the point transferred to***. (See 6.7 for transfers into blocks).  [ Note: However, the program can be terminated (by calling std::exit() or std::abort() (18.5), for example) without destroying class objects with automatic storage duration. —end note ]

Comment: That rule was in C++03, and probably C++98.  And it doesn't break C code because all C++ Standards allow an exception when the initialized object has a C-compatible type.

Comment: I'm not sure what prompts your comment about 'breaking C code'? Yes, intrinsics (PODs, I'm not sure right now) are a different beast. throughout the language. And, yes, as I explicitely show, the rules regarding jumps past initializers were more lax prior to C++11

Comment: C.1 is about differences between C and C++, not about differences between C++03 and C++11.  C++11 C.1.5 is not a change; it's identical to C++03 C.1.4.  You seem to be talking about the change to 6.7p3, which yes, breaks some C++03 code.

Comment: Wait, no. It's not possible for something to be a C++03 POD and not qualify for the wording in C++11 6.7p3, is it?

Comment: @aschepler Ah thanks. That explains :) I had my appendix names mixed up mentally. Thank you.

Comment: Re. 6.7p3, I'd say PODs fit the criteria (as long as they're declared without initializer, obviously)

Comment: so I still don't see what's a "breaking change".

Comment: Hi sehe, I've edited the question. Can you help me look at it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem with it, is that a local initialized variable is destroyed when you exit its scope. c++ thinks switch,if,while,for are all their own scope with regard to creating variables.

Comment: Well, now you even said it yourself! i dont understand what you dont understand, it simply sees it as its own scope - when you initialize(and not allocate) a local variable - it will be destroyed at the end of that scope.

Answer (score 0):

No, `x2` cannot be bypassed even if `i` is `1`. The problem with the `goto` would be that if it was taken, the constructor for `x1` would not be called (remember, the constructor is "called" at the `X x1;` statement - because the call to the constructor is *above* the target of the jump and you would be at a point where `x1` was still in scope.

But you can't jump past the line `X x2;` and end up in a point where `x2` is *still* in scope, so that is OK.

Comment: Hi Nik. I've edited the question. Can you help me look at it?